# Can a casino system prove my (divine) luck as cheating?

Tags: law, probability

I walked this morning and met a street fortune-teller. This old gypsy invited me to get my luck told, and she just blabbed those old nonsense phrases about how this day will be my lucky day and such. I gave her $5 for the morning encouragement (not really), smiled, and waved goodbye.

To my surprise, she grabbed my palm as I put the money in her hand and said that this will **really** be my lucky day. Anything I do throughout this day will yield a successful outcome, no matter what the odds against it are, but **only** if it's possible to happen in a day.

> **Clarification :** This means that you can't pull a 7 figure deal, because normally it requires several days to do the process. You just need a goal, and the odds will be in your favor.

Again, I nodded and didn't think about it much. But then a streak of luck hit me until I couldn't deny that this is real. (The events are irrelevant, but I can make some up if anyone is interested).

As of this writing, I'm on a plane to Vegas to be a new millionaire, no, a billionaire.

Wait, **what will happen when the casino learned I win in all of their games?** Will they suspect me of cheating? **Can they *prove* that I'm cheating even if I don't?** How can they blame me for getting the favor of the RNGods and the Lady of Luck?!!! It's unfair!

---

I know from the statistic it is possible to suspect him of cheating because the probability of winning in 4 different games (of slots) may be as well as astronomically improbable. However, he didn't bring anything suspicious, *he can prove that he's winning because of luck by playing in 3 different machines and he got all the jackpots **after they confronted him.*** (This might be important if a law allow you to dispute their decision or when you sue them)

What I don't know is how a casino(s) will react to this. I imagine they will have a system to weed out cheaters, but in this case they can't prove it. What will they do? Close the casino? Escort him out? Warn other casinos he might be coming?

For this question, I limit the games I play to *slot machines*. Surely I can't cheat on those, like I could for example by counting cards when playing Blackjack.

Although the story set in Vegas, I'm interested if anyone can provide information about the regulation/culture of other countries casinos, as I might as well change the place of the story if it is too unfavorable to do this in Vegas (I read that they can just kick you out and refuse to accommodate you even *after you prove your innocence*).

### How the luck works

Anything you wished, luck will *help* you to make it happens. Of course, if it's impossible, it won't happen. You don't know when the luck fails.

Think of how [Death Note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Note) works. Your wish "I want to be in Vegas next hour" while you're still in Africa now will just result in someone kidnap you and put you on plane to Vegas, while actually won't speed up the time needed to travel to Vegas.

Same thing will happen if it will take too long to process the wish; wishing for getting more than max bet will likely fail and you won't know that it won't work (no "wish denied" notification in your head), except there's occurrence in the past the casino allow exception on putting a bet higher than maximum. **We won't know exactly if something is possible or not,** but we can *rationale* whether it will work or not, like in the previous example.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64918/discussion-on-question-by-vylix-can-a-casino-system-prove-my-divine-luck-as-ch).

Comment: I suspect that when your luck drops off at midnight, you will end up dying a very wealthy man ;)

Comment: Since your luck can make anything you wish for happen, you'd wish for "getting away unscathed" after winning a ton. The casino owner will pine what a swell dude you are, and that if anyone should win, it ought to be you. You're just THAT lucky.

Comment: Limited to Slot Machines? I remember lots of stories about cheaters using them, they're probably the easiest things in a casino to actually cheat, I'd guess getting hassled would be virtually guaranteed after winning 2 or 3. If you're truly gifted with "random luck" you should be able to jump from game to game (human-run games) spending a few minutes at each and get win after win. THAT would be nigh-impossible to cheat at. But slot machines is like asking to get detained (maybe for hours) and kicked out.

Comment: If you're really that lucky, you won't get caught. Luckily, your activity risk factor (computed by the monitoring / fraud detection software installed in central server in basement) will be just a fraction below threshold. (Or maybe, the software / the machine will be out of service / in maintenance mode that particular day.)

Comment: You are in the same situation than people that mentally count cards at blackjack, without any device (that would definitely be cheating). I am not completely sure but casinos don't need to prove you are cheating. As it is a private place, they can just ask you to leave before loosing too much money

Comment: "the probability of winning in 4 different games (of slots) may be as well as astronomically improbable". The complexity of an event depends on the set it is picked from not its internal complexity. Odds are low but lots of ppl go Casio. Consider flipping coin and get 10 heads in row by all ppl in a stadium. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosecutor%27s_fallacy). As others already said Casinos don't care about math and statistics so this argument won't help you..

Comment: "There is no way to answer this question in a measurable way. This make it unfit for our community. Check the help center for more info."

Comment: The casinos don't need to prove you're cheating. If you win too much, they can just throw you out.

Comment: If you are wishing to be lucky enough to win a billion dollars and not get caught and accused of cheating by the casino, then your luck will revert to standard odds...  The odds of winning the money remain the same... but since the odds of getting caught and accused of cheating are pretty close to one.  Thus the best possible parse of the wish is to give you average joe gambling odds, which preserve the near zero accusation odds, because the casinos are only looking for those who beat the odds in unusual circumstances.

Comment: Yeah casino can toss you out without having any idea how you are cheating or even IF you are cheating.  Just look at the MIT students who were only beating the house they were not winning every time and they were using card counting which is completely legal, not that the casinos figured that out. Casinos can toss you at any time and if you are winning every time that will happen fast so better bet big fast.

Comment: This query is not story based. There's a nice story surrounding the central question, which is essentially a straight up ***casino policy on kicking one out onto the street*** question.  A.E.B.: *"What I don't know is how a casino(s) will react to this. I imagine they will have a system to weed out cheaters, but in this case they can't prove it. What will they do? Close the casino? Escort him out? Warn other casinos he might be coming?"* and also *"I'm interested if anyone can provide information about the regulation/culture of other countries casinos."*

Answer (score 141):

For "clear" probabilistic games (like roulette, where the probability of victory are well known, and 1/37 on a single number) they can easily tell, on statistic base, if you are cheating or not.

For "unclear"probabilistic games (like the equivalent of Windows solitaire, where it's not yet clear what are the chances of victory) they might not be able to tell with mathematical safety, but still they can suspect you.

In both cases they can simply kick you out of their premises, either with the good or the bad: casinos are not charity, they are there to make their own profit on the wallet of people, and if they see their profit is at risk (and be assured that a series of win for you put their profit at risk) they can simply refuse to allow you play further.

On the other hand, since it is your lucky day, it is very possible that the staff on duty for this kind of surveillance will not be available to expose you until few minutes after you have decided to leave the building. This would simply mean to accept a lower win and leave.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64919/discussion-on-answer-by-l-dutch-can-a-casino-system-prove-my-divine-luck-as-ch).

Comment: I assume what you mean about cheating on roulette is that if he were to always bet on a number (lets say 12) and 12 were to come up 6 times in a row it would be obvious it was rigged somehow. However it seems that if he were to switch his bet between different areas the fact that it was rigged would not be particularly obvious.

Comment: @Braydon Not really. If you bet on 12 six times in a row and win all of them, the casino will think "They've rigged the roulette wheel so that it always lands on 12." If you bet on six different numbers, and win all six bets, the casino will think "They've rigged the roulette wheel so that it lands on any number they choose." Six consecutive wins on different numbers is unlikely enough that it *will* raise questions about the legitimacy of your wins; expect to be questioned (and possibly searched), the wheel and ball to be inspected, etc. (cont.)

Comment: Of course, the game isn't rigged in a traditional sense, so there's nothing for the casino to actually find. It's a perfectly ordinary roulette wheel and ball, the attendant isn't working with you, and you have nothing that would allow you to influence the game on you. They'll still probably ask you to leave because you've cost them a lot of money, and they can't be certain they'll make any from you.

Answer (score 97):

Casinos don't need to find out that you are cheating. Or to be specific, how you are cheating.

For example card counting is not cheating, but when the casino discovers you are getting the upper hand in black jack they just politely ask you to leave. 
Casinos also share a database of their visitors and so they can mark certain customers as "not welcome".

If you stay only on machines you lower the chances of discovery, but you also lower the amount of money you can win.

It's easier and faster to just play scratch cards and different versions of lotto.

You can also start placing a large bet on some sport event.

Comment: What would happen if you have placed an equal bet on two opposite outcomes I wonder?

Comment: @charlie_pl *Fate* would choose the one where you would get more money. And if they both happen to be exactly equal - maybe the butterfly effect kicks in and you will be lucky to meet someone with the same interests by yelling loud enough that you won/lost?

Comment: @charlie_pl I imagine the host will not host (pun intended) a gamble that gives net result more than you have bet. For instance, in a 2 options gambling (win-lose), the odds will never be totaled more than 2. In 3 options, 3. And so forth. If it does, then you can just bet like you said: $1 on every option and always gain, albeit small, winning.

Comment: @Vylix Actually, if you bet an equal amount on all the options of a single game, you'd still lose...not win.  Don't forget the house edge.  Don't believe me, go bet 1 dollar on all 38 numbers on a roulette wheel and tell me how much you won when they give you $35.

Comment: @charlie_pl a casino/bookie is never going to give 2:1 payout to 2:1 odds. Often by allowing a significant chance for a third possibility

Comment: @charlie_pl The problem only exist if you play in game with only two outcomes with the same payout. Which for example exist in roulette. You can gamble on red and black. But the luck for you may mean you won't loose money. So the table may broke physically during your bet.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY, there is 0 and 00 which are green.

Comment: @ViktorMellgren yes but it's not payable in the same way as red and black. So if you put 1 on red, black and 0 zero is always the more profitable option.

Comment: @charlie_pl: Reminds me of the episode of The Monkees where they desperately needed to lose a roulette bet, so they bet on cyan 100. And won.

Comment: @Hurkyl [Here's that segment](https://youtu.be/cSLZ1SYhz5U?t=846).

Comment: @Draco18s for reference, the numbers they actually pick are 24 red, 212 green, and 87 plaid; the first two come up but the chase scene starts before the last one is actually spun.

Comment: If you really want to win without the casino chasing you out or marking you as "not welcome", play Poker. Whether you win or you lose, the house still wins, so they don't care if you're cheating or not (at least until the other players start suspecting you).

Comment: @Nolonar A consecutive winner in poker is also not good for house because he attract people watching and not bidding while at the same time people lower their bidding on other tables because they assume that if someone else wins the casino will cheat on the to get even.

Comment: Presumably, the scratch cards would have been printed before the lucky day, so wrt "but only if it's possible to happen in a day", the best you could do in scratch cards is happen to have enough other people buy a ticket that day that you end up with the best card on the roll. This is very unlikely to be the big jackpot (on average it will be significantly less than the cost of a ticket times the number of tickets on a roll). The sports bet would work especially well with an accumulator - multiple individual outcomes that must all happen, leading to very high pay out.

Comment: @DeveloperInDevelopment I assume the luck works the way that you are handled the winning card.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY the point is if you play red/black evens the house will still win (i.e. on average, make a profit at your expense) because there are 0s.

Comment: I think the point of @charlie_pl's question was, how would the (magic?) luck function (not, would this be a good way to win money even without special luck), if you bet on two opposing outcomes? It would be impossible for you to win both. The OP says "Of course, if it's impossible, it won't happen."

Comment: @LarsH That's why my answer was that the luck would act in a way to nullify the bet.

Comment: @charlie_pl Irresistible force vs immovable object lol. In any case, "divine luck" will probably act in such a way that only the winning wager gets accepted, e.g. the "wrong" bet is never entered into the system because of a computer glitch or human error.

Answer (score 67):

Here is what you should do.

1. Play progressive slots that can pay out hundreds of thousands on one win, and someone has to do it.  This will not alert the casino in any way.  You will also get a huge crowd.  Progressive slots work kind of like the lottery.  Every play sets aside some money for a jackpot.  One lucky winner gets the jackpot. Pick one that has at least 300,000 or more.  For the casino, this is not their money, this is a jackpot they will pay sooner or later, similar to how a lottery works.
2. Tell everyone in the crowd you are going to super double down.  You are going to bet it all on the lucky number 13, and anyone who gives you good luck vibes gets 100 bucks.
3. Get a giant crowd.  Bet your 300,000 on 13.  Get paid over 10 million.  Walk with your crowd to the cashier. You are untouchable.  Get paid, spend 10 or 20 thousand giving out the hundreds you promised.

At this point the casino may be unhappy losing so much money but they would have very little to complain about.  There would only be 2 data points, not nearly enough to find any pattern.  You would have won at games where you have zero control so they could not claim any cheating.  Even if they claim you cheating, you would have a crowd surrounding you that watch you win fairly.  The casino would know that if they don't pay you they may have a riot on their hands, as well as pretty much a guarantee to make the news. Ten million may be a lot, but not "national news story that they don't pay if you win" a lot.  No matter how mad they would be, you would be untouchable.

If you are still greedy, go buy new cloths and a hat, go to another casino and do it again.

Comment: If you pass out $100 bills to random people in a casino you will start a riot.

Comment: I think with many slot machines you cannot get lucky because there isn't any chance going inside. These machines are programmed to ensure a certain outcome for the house. Although I suppose you might get lucky and find the one machine that had a bug in its programming.

Comment: @joeytwiddle yes, slot machines have programmed odds - but what if he's just really lucky and finds the one that's about to pay out? No one is saying that he's modifying outcomes, just that he's so lucky *he always picks the correct outcome*

Comment: +1 For the idea about progressive slots - I learnt something today. However, I don't think there's a casino which lets you bet 300,000$ on a single number on the roulette.

Comment: looks like the highest bet in vegas may be $123,000 That slows you down, but not by too much

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt A riot just makes it easier to slip out in all the chaos :)

Comment: @joeytwiddle Actually, slot machines are random. Unlike most computers that can only generate pseudo random numbers, slots have extra true random generators. Generally, these are something like accelerometers where the random vibrations of air pressure are used to generate randomness. Your odds of winning are still set. But the chances are actually random within your odds.

Comment: If you win a lot of money in a slot machine payout (or any casino game), you won't be getting the money that night.  They investigate high payouts before actually handing over the money.  HOWEVER... if you were to tweak the premise and simply tell the casino that you are willing to put up what they owe you, the owners could extend a one-time agreement that would allow you to bet your winnings as outlined.  It would take luck because the board of directors would probably need to be assembled to allow it, but it IS your lucky day...

Comment: @Shane - Have you not heard about the Russian hackers who reverse engineered a particular make of slot machine? See [wired.com article](https://www.wired.com/2017/02/russians-engineer-brilliant-slot-machine-cheat-casinos-no-fix/)

Comment: @joeytwiddle: Nope. Not even that : https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2017/06/sorry-maam-you-didnt-win-43m-there-was-a-slot-machine-malfunction/ the bank always wins

Comment: @joeytwiddle We can't worry about how the machines are programmed. That kind of thinking is just saying that the universe is predetermined, and there is no such thing as luck. The machine pays sometimes, and luck will have it that it will pay out to you.

Answer (score 31):

The key to not being kicked out for winning too much is to win a big sum at once, then change casino. Las Vegas has so many casinos that you probably won't be able to visit all of them, but if you concentrate on the "high yield" ones (i.e., those allowing the greatest bets), you'll make a great deal of money pretty quickly. At the end of the day, you can even come back to a previous casino you visited: by that time, others will have won the jackpot, and if you dress differently than before you probably won't be recognized.

But what to play? I don't know the maximum yield of slot machines, but I know that the roulette is a sure way to go. Since your bet is multiplied by 35, and that you can win twice in a row without raising too much suspicion, this could theoretically multiply your base bet by 1225! However, all bets are subject to a maximum. I'm not rich enough to have played those maxima, but I would say that finding a roulette with a maximum bet of \$10,000 is possible. This could then yield as much as \$350,000 per casino (\$700,000 if you play twice, "it's my lucky day" style).

Another advantage of the roulette is that it is in fact much harder to cheat (you can't really tamper with the machine without witness), and the probability of winning twice in a row is not that low compared to some slot machine jackpot (but you bet more). So it is less suspicious than winning on multiple slot machines.

Last thing: when you win, cash in immediately in case the casino wants to kick you out without exchanging your tokens for money.

Comment: I am not sure whether the casino can really withhold your money if they don't have anything to prove you were trying to win money by fraud. [This answer of Law.SE seems to support this](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/1543), though the attention there was not that great. Do you have any source to support that they can withhold your money if they kick you out?

Comment: @Secespitus I have no source on this, but I was under the assumption that the tokens you gain, not being actual money, can be withold if they suspect you acquired it by cheating. Better be safe than sorry, at least they surely can't withold actual money.

Comment: I was mostly relying on the answer I mentioned and the comments. Specifically `I think the casino is bound to cash out chips on demand by the chip bearer. To my senses, casino chips are a de facto debt instrument redeemable by the bearer. Consider the following legal theories of reasonable expectation, implied-in-fact contract, legitimate expectations and estoppel.` But I am by no means a lawyer, so I totally agree with the `Better safe than sorry` approach. Just wanted to check whether you knew something more about this than I do.

Comment: Although this is an interesting method to get away with the win, I'm afraid this does not answer the question: **What would/can casino do to me?**. Can you expand your answer to address this?

Comment: Besides that, if you make it out with the chips, hawk them. They're almost as good as cash.

Comment: the casino cannot withhold your winnings, the worst they can do is try to distract a winner from leaving  (free rooms, shows, meeting celebrities, ect.) in hopes of keeping you in the casino so you will to lose it some other way.

Comment: Max yeild on a slot machine is in the millions, Megabucks and other cumulative machines can have rare huge payouts, https://www.caesars.com/casino-gaming-blog/latest-posts/casino-news/jackpot-winners/biggest-casino-jackpot-wins-ever#.WaR3VyiGPIU

Comment: While casino security is definitely there to catch cheats, they also serve the very important function of reassuring management that they lost fair and square when a customer does manage to pull off a huge win.

Comment: "cash in immediatly in case the casino wants to kick you out without exchanging your tokens for money" - Surely that would be illegal, exposing the casino to legal action and liability for damages above and beyond the face value of the chips.

Answer (score 24):

### $40 Million Easily

According to [this article](https://lasvegassun.com/news/2014/dec/10/jackpot-here-are-some-biggest-slot-payouts-las-veg/) on largest payouts.  The current record for a slot machine was a 100 dollar bet yielding a $39,710,826.36 payout.  So your incredible luck should be able to land you a win worth that much in one pull if you choose a slot machine that has an unclaimed jackpot prize.  So at this point there is no cheating to even prove.

### $100 Million limit With Only Using Slot Machines

There are two challenges in your way with using slot machines to get to one billion.  First, casinos have caps on the max you are allowed to bet, and normal slot machines are no exception.  Second, there are only so many slot machines that have jackpot prizes worth enough to make a dent in that one billion target.
Not to mention winning more than two of those jackpot prizes would likely net you a lot of negative public attention, so your luck might kick in and prevent you from winning any more.  As such two jackpots and some very good miscellaneous slot machine playing likely will not yield enough to break the 100 million mark without something bad happening (which your luck will work hard to prevent).

Modern slot machines are controlled by computers and activity on them is monitored and logged.  If you start to exceed the expected average return (which varies by machine to machine) it will send up red flags to the control room.  At which point they are going to want to question you, to see if you are willing to explain how you are cheating.  No matter what you will get kicked out and black listed from not just that casino but likely all other casinos on the strip, and entering any of them would count as trespassing.  Once you get black listed your luck will likely let you enter any casino without getting caught, but it likely will prevent you from winning anything since it will attract attention to you and result in your arrest.

Your luck would also not use technical glitches to secure your winnings since [glitches can void your winnings](http://www.cnn.com/2016/11/01/us/slot-machine-winner-steak-dinner-trnd/index.html).  That combined with no evidence of you tampering with the machines or using a device, could lead the casino to assume you had inside help.  So your good luck could result in some rather bad luck for the employees of that establishment, so please factor this in before you go on your winning spree.

### Use the 40-100 Million to Invest in Penny Stocks

$1 Billion and beyond can be obtained via investing in high risk stocks.  Your luck will allow you to randomly pick the cheap companies that end up getting bought out or invested in by bigger companies causing their stock prices to jump up by an order of magnitude with one of the [largest being 24,000%](http://nypost.com/2014/07/11/trading-suspended-after-penny-stock-jumps-24000/).  So your luck should let you pick a set of stocks that will yield a ridiculous one day return without triggering the Extraordinary Event Halt code.

You will still need to pay taxes on your incredible earnings.  There is no amount of luck that can save you from taxes or the IRS.

Comment: There isn't enough liquidity in the entire penny stock market to soak up that much investment.  And wouldn't a teeny tiny ROI still count as a win?

Comment: -1 for gambling the stock market! I had enought spam about stock market I don't come here to read about it.

Comment: If you win a lot of money in a slot machine payout (or any casino game), you won't be getting the money that night.  They investigate high payouts before actually handing over the money.  Thus I don't think you could re-invest mega-winnings in the same day.

Comment: Tax depends on your jurisdiction - since the asker mentioned Vegas, that suggests the USA. However, in the UK, gains made from gambling are not taxable, so long as you're not a professional gambler (so make sure you have some sort of paying job). You can 'gamble' on the stock market with Spread Betting (like CFDs in other locations), and again be tax-free. Repatriating money to other jurisdictions may require some more super-luck though ;-) Super-luck, it seems, starts with booking the right plane ticket!

Answer (score 16):

Let us put out of the way the last part of the question: "What would/can casino do to me?"

Casino has *no* way to *prove* you are cheating, so they cannot legally negate you your wins.

What they *can* do is to deny you right to play again, so your strategy is to delay that as much as possible, very possibly till when your lucky day expires (BTW how do you do that? will it expire on midnight, Cinderella style? If so: which Time Zone? Current? Your own home? Be wary of "that last big bet" being after timeout!).

If you win each and everything you try you will be suspected and kicked out, if OTOH you mostly win, but sometime "wish to lose this one", things will go much more unnoticed.

Real casinos welcome occasional "incredible" wins because they are good advertisement, better than anything else.

Key is not overdo your hand (and disappear fast after you leave the casino).

Other thing to do is to attract a lot of attention so you get a "public" around you which will make very difficult for casino to kick you out.

Playing recklessly (e.g.: "tiers de tout") and occasionally losing may also be recommended.

Since you already wasted a good part of your "Lucky Day" jumping from one casino to the next might not be a good idea.

Comment: Upvoted for the "wish to lose this time" idea.  If your luck takes the big picture into account, losing when you want to avoid getting kicked out is definitely lucky.  Or maybe your luck includes the casino staff missing the pattern of your wins :P

Comment: Maybe it ends exactly 24 hours from the start time?

Answer (score 10):

Since you are *incredibly* lucky today, why would the luck stop? Perhaps they don't notice you. Perhaps they let you go on suspicion that you'll come back and they'll bust you then. Perhaps it was *everyone else's unlucky* and the casino actually didn't lose a massive fortune; they just accept it as a wash. Perhaps you smile and the casino manager believes you.

> For this question, I limit the games I play to slot machines. Surely I can't cheat on those, like I could for example by counting cards when playing Blackjack.

There have been cases of cheating in the past with slot machines. Mainly around developer hiding code (i.e. if the machine detects a certain pattern of coin insertions, it does a certain action).

The machines are heavily regulated which makes the odds very predictable. Well... IGT/Gtech is owned by the Italian mafia.....that's another reason why they are so regulated. I'd think playing at the Poker table, where you are "stealing" other peoples' money, would be less suspicious than the slots. The casino isn't losing money then.

Comment: Although this is an interesting method to get away with the win, I'm afraid this does not answer the question: **What would/can casino do to me?**. Can you expand your answer to address this? +1 for the developer part.

Comment: @Vylix They would simply throw you out, whether they can demonstrate that you cheated or not. Why are you operating under the assumption that a business such as a casino has to prove anything to deny service to you?

Comment: Because in my common sense, if they can't prove your cheating, they should not (and can't, by law) throw you out. I know this is the case in US, that's what I already stated in my question, but I am also looking if there's somewhere this is not allowed, so I can move my story there.

Comment: @Vylix They surely can. Almost every establishment nowadays has __admission rights__. That means they can kick you out, and not let you in, under any circumstances they see fit. Yes, not liking you is one such circumstance.

Comment: @tfrascaroli I guess the exception would be if they kick you out because of discrimination, right? But if they just kick you out without giving a reason they are fine.

Comment: @Lichtbringer Sure, discrimination wouldn't be acceptable.... but the sad truth is that we have discrimination all over the place. But that's completely different from what the OP is asking about. I think, as you say, that if they just don't give a reason other than "admission rights reserved" they just kick your butt out!

Answer (score 8):

If you're trying to maximize profit, minimize risk, your best "bet" is a single, high-payout gamble, or in other words, Powerball (of course, it would really need to be your lucky day to ensure they were doing a drawing that evening).  Although the odds against winning are astronomical, you know you will win, and you winning isn't automatically any more suspicious than anyone else winning.

If you have any pattern of suspicious wins at a casino, *they can ban you at will, they don't need a justification.*  And, at least according to [*Bringing Down the House*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bringing_Down_the_House_(book)), extralegal enforcement is still a Vegas reality.  In other words, an overly "lucky" winner might get a visit from a tough guy... or just disappear.

Modern casinos are incredibly sensitive to any threat to profits.  They're perfectly happy to ban someone just for being lucky, even if no cheating at all is ever observed.  The advantage, to you, for a lottery,  is that it's always expected that someone will win.  No one has a vested interest in that money not being paid out.

Answer (score 8):

The short legal answer is this:

**You're on private property, they can escort you out and ask you not to return for any reason or none. You have no right to be there, you only have permission.**

This applies in basically any country on any private premises, not just casinos. The following is an extract from an article giving guidance to door staff on [how to eject someone from the premises](http://www.workingthedoors.co.uk/safer-doors/trespassing-laws/).

> Licensed premises offer what is called an ‘open invitation’ to members of the public to enter, whether on payment or otherwise, for an evenings entertainment. That invitation, however, may be withdrawn at any time. Door supervisors, acting on behalf of the licensee, have the right in law to refuse admission to anyone whose presence is not welcome. Further to this, customers already on the premises may become trespassers if the invitation to remain is withdrawn and they refuse to leave when asked to.
>   [...]
>   It is also within the licensing laws that police officers are required to assist with ejecting customers who are refusing to leave if requested to do so by the licensee or his employee or agent, and they may use such force as may be required to effect their purpose.

They don't need to prove you were cheating unless they're intending to take you to court for it. They don't really even need to suspect you were cheating, they just need to suspect you of winning too much for their bank balance and can eject you at any point *with the assistance of the police* by the simple expedient of revoking your permission to be in the building.

**You'd better hope luck is on your side to prevent them from really noticing you.**

You can help with this by not sitting on any one table or one game for long. A couple of games here, a couple there. Stay away from the blackjack tables because those are closely watched for card counting. Roulette and craps (as long as you don't touch the dice) are probably fine to wander between. Bet big, win big, but move on. Don't watch the tables before playing, don't act like you have a system, don't interact much with anyone else.

Acting like a giddy tourist having a lucky day is probably fine, it's likely how you'll be acting anyway.

Comment: Your answer is the answer. The casino doesn't have to prove he cheated. Winning too often and he must be cheating. Banned and on the black list. I know I thought of something similar, but you won. However, the lucky day luck should enable him to win big & win quickly without being noticed. It's luck after all, it doesn't have to make sense. Assuming means "day' in the normal sense of the word & get out reasonably promptly before the luck runs out.

Comment: As the only answer that cites resource outside US, I hereby grant the bounty.

Answer (score 7):

Winning once or in a short period of time is very suspicious, and as noted multiple times, the casino is going to take steps to ban you and ensure you will be banned from other casinos as well.

At any rate, winning the slots once is thinking too small. What you need to do is spend your day schmoozing with progressively higher level members of the Casino's staff and organization. Each step should be designed to ingratiate you with senior staff, management and quickly the owners. Because you are lucky, everything you say will resonate positively, and they will be agreeable to taking you aboard, not as a gambler, but as a partner in the Casino's ownership structure.

Now you don't have to worry about broken kneecaps, and your stream of income will last for years to come, along with free tickets to Penn and Teller magic shows, celebrity chef restaurants, Cirque du Soleil or whatever other things you fancy. In fact, you will make your new friends forever grateful if you mention you *heard* that a certain gypsy might put your mutual investment at risk......

Answer (score 6):

Gambling analysis and casino technology is some of the best in the world.  The casino would very quickly discover something was wrong because they know the odds of every single game and machine in their building and always have analysis running to determine if winning is within the probability of the machine payout.

- If your winner won too many games, he'd be invited to leave.
- If your winner won on too many machines (either one machine too many times or multiple machines), those machines would be taken out of service, then he'd be invited to leave.

Unless he took the casino for too much money, then he'd be invited to a back room where an educational question-and-answer session totally (not involving lead pipes and broken knuckles) would take place while the casino figures out how he did it.  Following that, two dark figures would visit the fortuneteller with an aesthetically pleasing bag to put over her head, after which she would either explain to the casino how she could bend probability in the casino's favor or she would enjoy a restful sleep with the fishes.  It wouldn't matter to them at all whether or not she was the arbiter of good fortune or simply a person identifying that good fortune.  That's not their problem.

Do you think this is unfair?  That's funny... the casino thinks what you're doing is unfair (a) because you're modifying the natural course of probability and (b) you're doing it with their money.  Not surprisingly, (b) is more important than (a).  It's just business, after all....

Comment: Can you clarify the "Unless ... he did it." part? I'm not sure I get the meaning.

Comment: Quibble:  In Vegas, one does not sleep wit da fishes. There's a lot more sand than water, and freshly-dug graves aren't one bit obvious like they are where ground cover must be disturbed.

Comment: @Vylix, casinos track everything, including how much money every individual wins.  If their analysis suggests you've won more money than is statistically possible, they start asking questions.  Money isn't free.

Comment: Quibble: Casinos don't beat people up (at least not anymore). Not for card counting, for which they'll just make you leave. And not even for actually cheating - they'll detain you long enough for the police to come get you.

Comment: @stannius :-) that really is a quibble since it was nothing more than good humor.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of answers here seem to be answering the related but un-asked question of "How does the lucky person get away with it or maximize winnings?"

The answer to the actual question is rather simple and short...

### How can the casino prove I'm cheating?

If you are not cheating, they cannot prove that you are. How would they? The casino cannot prove something when there is no proof.

The casino could try to plant fake evidence. This is unlikely to happen unless you are breaking the bank for any given, specific casino. Some people do walk away with millions, and the casinos don't plant evidence against them all, so why would you be different?

If you are raking in *Billions* from 1 single casino, *then* maybe they would try something. At that point, though, what they are doing is illegal, so just use your imagination. Maybe they rig their own roulette game in a fashion that you could for cheating and they say you did it, maybe get false witnesses. There are 1000 things they could do here.

Speaking of illegal activity, casinos are highly regulated in a lot of ways. It is illegal even for the casino to tamper with their own devices to cheat in the casino's favor, just like it is illegal for you to tamper with them to cheat.

That said, they will definitely *suspect* you of cheating. There have been times when people have cheated, the casinos have looked into them and proven they did cheat, and those people have gone to jail.

### What Can (or Will) the Casino do?

Even though the casino cannot *prove* you are cheating, that doesn't matter. They don't need to prove it. They can and will simply kick you out. It is that simple.

If you keep winning too much money in a way that does no good for the casino (provides no positive publicity for casino, causes nobody around you to bet more, etc.), eventually someone will come over and just force you to leave.

### What Else is the Casino Likely to do?

Planting evidence is unlikely, as mentioned above, since that could get the casino in big trouble. However, that does not mean the casino will just roll over. I will also go into the situation where you try to get one last big win so the casino has little time to react, but I will cover it from the casino's point of view, per your question.

I have heard of people being denied their winnings before. Even if this is illegal (some have suggested it is, and I would agree), that does not bother the casino if they do not lose out. This, then, becomes just another bet, another game of chances. Odds are that people who are not given all the chips they deserve are not going to take legal action against the casino, and even if some do then the casino just pays you what you were owed in the first place. That is: there is no negative for the casino since they lose (approximately) the same amount whether they pay you now or pay you when your lawyers threaten them and so there is little incentive to bully you into leaving without all earnings, but there is much positive for the casino if you don't send lawyers. So it's a "win/not-lose" situation for the casino to bully you into not taking that last big winning when they are kicking you out.

Further, if you have no witnesses or evidence, it may be hard to prove that you were denied what was rightfully yours. If you leave without all your winnings when the casino bullies you, what proof do you have that you actually were denied what was yours? If you were keeping a low profile, you likely left few or no witnesses. This makes it even easier for the casino to withhold what is yours.

### Summary

The casino can't prove anything but doesn't need to. The casino can and will kick you out. It is possible they might try to bully you into leaving without all your money.

Answer (score 5):

A casino can kick you out at any time. They will immediately put you on a ban list that gets circulated. They would probably even put a person on you to warn other casinos. In the US they need to prove you are cheating. They may hold your funds to review security but they cannot not pay because you were unbelievably lucky. But they are going to shut you down pretty fast.

A poker pro *beat* two casinos in what was fair play.  Phil Ivey got an edge and he did not technically cheat.  They held his money and he is suing for the winnings.

I suspect they would just shut slots down if three jackpots hit in a row even if it was different people.

Comment: Something is wrong in your anecdote, poker isn't played against the house it's played against other punters, the house doesn't get involved (presumably unless there's foul play).

Comment: @Separatrix Something is wrong with you assuming he was playing poker.

Comment: So why mention that he was a poker pro without saying what he was playing, which is significantly more important to the story. You're leading me to assume he was playing poker.

Comment: @Separatrix If I said a famous actor beat the house would you assume they were acting.   He is known as a poker pro.

Comment: There's no implication of what an actor would be playing, fine he wasn't playing poker, what was he playing? Your anecdote is still lacking, give it a source at least.

Comment: Google phil ivey beats casino

Comment: @Separatrix this is not an academic resource. We don't require sources. It is a verifiable statement. Nowhere does it say in the rules that a citation is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Why go to casinos? You can put all your money into FOREX, fool around with their system for half a day, and become richer than your wildest dream.

Or, do online betting. You can pick the most important sports event of the day, predict in when your favorite team will score and win a ton of money.

Another way, and much more to my liking, is to go to a chemistry lab, enter the first door on the right and start talking to people who are trying to synthesize the first room temperature superconductor. Play the luck game by telling them what should they mix and in what quantity, and create that magic material. Then write the patent with your new friends and sell it for a few billions.

Comment: Although this is an interesting method to get away with the win, I'm afraid this does not answer the question: What would/can casino do to me?. Can you expand your answer to address this?

Comment: What a shame actually, I love the last part. People get creative until they forgot what the actual question is :(

Comment: These are good ideas, but as has been explained by the OP of the question you are not answering the real question. These are more like suggestions that would come after a part like "Now that we covered your question, here are some suggestions for your story:" Your answer is currently in the low-quality review queue and might get deleted if you don't [edit] it and focus on the main question asked in the first part of your answer.

Comment: @Secespitus this does address the question. They're question is how to formulate their story. This answer is stating that the intended manner of winning billions is not correct.

Comment: @Typhon The OP, Vylix, explained in a comment above that this answer does not answer his question. WorldBuilding does not deal with formulating a story. The focus is on creating the world. A frame challenge should be accompanied by an actual answer to the question.

Comment: @Secespitus it does. He asked how best to make billions. You cannot do that in Vegas. Therefore, this is a correct answer.

Comment: @Typhon The part about becoming a billionaire is stil fluff. The real question is stated in a separate paragraph in bold letters under that statement `Wait, what will happen when the casino learned I win in all of their games? Will they suspect me of cheating? Can they prove that I'm cheating even if I don't?` You might be interested in [this Meta discussion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5310/rage-quit-frustration-as-a-factor-in-question-removal) about answers going off on a tangent and ignoring the main question. The bounty message makes this even clearer.

Comment: @Secespitus I was told by the moderation team when flagging such answers that in order for a post to be considered worthy of deletion is must *intentionally and blatantly* ignore the post entirely. The post has to actually in some way be spam or be intentionally ignoring the post and not addressing it. Therefore, this post shouldn't be in the review queue. Are the moderators on this site more strict then MSE? If so, then that's a relief.

Comment: @Typhon Every site is slightly different and while we all adhere to the same basic concepts and values there might be slight differences in moderation. And of course it's users who primarily moderate the site, so there may be differences depending on who is reviewing something. This answer is probably not in the low-quality review queue anymore. It would have been deleted by now if enough users thought it was worthy of deletion. When flagging you seee `This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the **question**.` so there is good reason to in my opinion to flag this.

Answer (score 4):

### "Anything I do throughout this day will yield a successful outcome, no matter what the odds against it are, but only if it's possible to happen in a day."

Let's assume this is literally the rule that has been applied.

For your scenario involving casino gambling, no, you would not be throw out. You wouldn't win much either. A "successful outcome" is not necessarily a bountiful outcome.

Also, time constrained blessings traditionally have backlash worse than their benefit once the time expires. Win a dollar today? Lose three dollars tomorrow.

Me? Spend the day trying not to be too successful.

---

### "Can a casino system prove my (divine) luck as cheating?"

No, they can't prove cheating due to divinely enhanced intrinsic luck. They can (and probably will) suspect cheating. They can kick you out for no reason (right to refuse service to anyone). But they can't prove cheating.

---

### Slot Machines

Slot machines in casinos these days are typically tied to a central computer system. Machines that show unusual distributions are taken out of service. I think your best bet is play a random machine, win the jackpot (though, see above, re: "successful outcome"), move on to another casino and repeat.

Comment: Interesting information about the centralized slot system. +1

Comment: Slot machines also give you the highest payout and the least investment, the record is 40 million from a single jackpot at 100 dollar slot machine. They also advertise what the highest payout is so you can find the best bet easily. note however megajackpots usually garner some media attention so you should not do it many times.

Answer (score 3):

Most casinos have a "big deal wheel" under some name that has a highest payout that increases over time (and resets when it is won).  If it is your lucky day, then you likely walk into a casino when the payout hasn't been claimed in a few days.  That payout can be in the double digit $millions.  All it takes is 1 pull and you won.  This will raise no suspicion because most people only get 1 pull on it and someone has to win it some time.  The loss is already in their balance sheet. So, they won't be coming after you unless you hit more than one casino.

That is, unless they are specifically looking for lucky people for some other purpose.  Then the "big deal wheel" might just be a way to give them a list of people for further study.

You might be able to have them deposit that money into a FOREX or day trader account and multiply it some (10% increase per trade isn't that great on \$100.00 but it's pretty nice on $10,000,000).  It all depends on how long it takes to get the money into your account.  If it comes to it, you can likely find someone to give you cash now (at a lower amount) for the prize you just won.  Heck the casino might do it and consider it a profit (the loss of the full amount is already on the books).

As for a noticeable winning streak using other methods, the casinos can kick you out for any or no reason.  "We have the right to refuse service" is a fairly ingrained concept in US businesses.  They can also ban you and send your name and photo to the other casinos.  All of this is legal and common practice.

As far as back room knuckle breakers, that's not legal action so it depends on the story.

Answer (score 2):

### Kay Eye Double-Ell you

The casino business has much mellowed, but let's face it - it's not run by pandas.

It's never happened, so we don't know what would happen if someone  demonstrated statistically impossible luck, and was seen by the wrong person.  I think first it would be treated as cheating, that person would be detained in a more-or-less lawful fashion while the cheating was checked out.  They would inevitably have to be released.

However, if word got out about their paranormal luck, it's very likely less legal things would happen, possibly waiting for them as they walk out of the detention area.  Less a matter of the impoverished casino wanting to kill them, and more a matter of others wanting to exploit that luck for themselves.  They could find themselves in a mobile kidnapping, escorted by toughs from casino to casino.  This could make a scene at a casino, so more likely they'd haul them to some nondescript sportsbook office.

Our hero might try to "sour the milk", so for you OP, this raises a question of how the luck works exactly. Can they will to lose, or is the winning compulsory?

Of course, criminal stupidity being what it is, this is all likely to end in a shallow grave.

Alternately, he might meet a white-knight who bargains, and says "you bring the luck, I bring the capitalization" and allows our hero to make a lot more money than he could otherwise, and a bunch of orphanages get funded.  But of course there's no drama in that.

The upshot is for our hero to avoid having a sack over his head, he needs to be not detected.

### Avoiding detection

As they say... Once is happenstance.  Twice is coincidence.  **Three times is enemy action**.

For them, it's about the laws of large numbers.  Don't give them a large enough sample size.  Winning your first two hands in blackjack is commonplace, probably a 1 in 5 chance, so not anywhere near "enemy action".  Winning your first two plays in *roulette* has a 1 in 1000ish chance - *that's enemy action*.

So you have to contain your wins at each table to "happenstance" and your observable activity at the casino to "coincidence".

Spreading your wins across *a wide variety* of games will remove accusations of cheating -- since cheating is always particular to one specific game.

There's a perfectly good rationale: You say you walked away after your first-play win, because the game is now jinxed, and you've used up your luck. If they want more, you arm-wave the hard science of the laws of large numbers, and the widely-held corollary that *after a win, another win is less likely*. The casino is unlikely to argue with that, since it implies if you had lost, you'd have kept playing.

Comment: @Vylix legally not much, but extralegally, sky's the limit. Whether it's the casino proper, a shadow arm of the casino, or genuine third parties.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the sample size small in the casinos and the odds long. If someone slightly beats the odds on a blackjack table for a few hours they'll see themselves kicked out and banned. Betting 3 times on number 23 at the roulette wheel and winning 3 times in a row on the other hand is much harder to catch.

Since it pays off at 35 to 1 you only need a small number of wins.

You want to find the casino with the highest limit on the roulette wheel. Apparently that's the Luxor with $123,000,000 per spin.

go with single numbers for 35 to 1  odds.

With a few thousand dollars seed money (I'm assuming a stating $4000) and guaranteed success you can probably manage to hit the table limit in 3 spins of the roulette wheel.

You then place 123,000,000 on a single number.

You walk out of the casino a billionaire with $4,305,000,000 after a remarkably lucky 4 spins of roulette wheels.

that's not a large enough sample size for them to prove cheating.

it's also fast enough to pull off before they can kick you out.

Comment: Odds are very good that the pit boss will notice if you win a 35 to 1 twice in a row, or just the fact that you're getting paid out 140k in chips.   Then again, if you  are infinitely lucky, then the odds don't matter.

Comment: yes? of course they'll notice but 

1 win:nothing out of the ordinary. 

2 wins: not suspicious, after all, casinos make lots of money from people who keep trying their luck until they lose. 

staff member running the game probably changed to be sure. 

3 wins: "holy shit" but still not really proof of cheating. "hopefully he keeps going so he can lose and it doesn't screw up this months balance sheets."

Tops stakes are now in play on a high-roller table. Might make him change table and staff members again. 

4 wins: he is now a billionaire.

Comment: I would not bet the same number again and again, they might think the wheel is broken.

Comment: The odds of four lucky spins is 1 to about 2 million. With over 3 million visitors each month, you can expect that to happen every month.

Answer (score 2):

> Anything I do throughout this day will yield a successful outcome, no
>   matter what the odds against it are, but **only** if it's possible to
>   happen in a day.

The key here is `successful outcome`.  If the success is what you want it to be, for any given bet you can choose the success.  That success may end up being that you don't win on that bet in order to allow you stay under the radar.  If you walk in and put a few bets in a row on something and come up as a big winner, it might look strange.  If you build a betting history, then it might look favourable.

Reaching back to the slot machine idea from others, you could lose a few machines before getting lucky on one which has a huge jackpot; all by defining *your* version of a successful outcome before you play a particular spin.  You may build up a 'pot' of a few thousand dollars, blow half of it on a very high jackpot payout machine before it drops several million for you.

> what will happen when the casino learned I win in all of their games?

By picking your winning times and losing times, a casino might not notice at all.  Give them a bit of money and then get lucky at odd points which ultimately net you a lot in one go might just be seen as a statistical anomaly or just fluke.  Winning all of the time would draw a lot of attention to yourself and you would likely be asked to leave and/or barred from visiting again.

> Can they *prove* that I'm cheating even if I don't?

No, but they don't have to.  They can just remove you from the premises.

Answer (score 2):

JBH's answer made me think of something.
"The casino would very quickly discover something was wrong because they know the odds of every single game and machine in their building and always have analysis running to determine if winning is within the probability of the machine payout".

What if the luck he has was bending the outcome for the others as well? Making it so that the automatic systems of the casino would not detect things too much out of the ordinary, except that all the substantial winnings would be those of our lucky guy, while the rest of people would not win much, leaving the statistics of the casino pretty much stable. As long as you keep a low profile, they might not notice that the guy who won at the slot machine is the same that just won good money at the roulette.
Note: these won't make you a billionaire, as all these winning should be not too high.

Alternatives:
You could go for one single very high win. Again, you don't become a billionaire, but there would not necessarily be anything suspicious in one single big strike of luck.

If you want to add some more won money without making it suspicious, on your way to Vegas you should stop somewhere to buy some of those scratch-to-win tickets (I am not sure about the correct name). Those cannot be cheated, and also cannot be traced by the casino.

Comment: Hello *LisaD*! Please don't write into your answer that you are not allowed to write a comment and are therefore intentionally misusing the answer feature to substitute the comment feature. It would be good to [edit] that part out, otherwise this might get deleted as that's a normal deletion reason. Answers should stand on their own, though they can of course reference existing answers. I think your answer stands on its own. You can comment once you reach 50 reputation (which you should have after I upvoted your answer ;) ). If you have a moment please take the [tour] to learn more about WB.SE

Comment: A little tip: you can notify one user per comment by writing an "@" in front of their username, for example @Secespitus. It even autocompletes the name for you. The OP of a post is always notified. In this case I received a notification because my comment was the only one under your post, which is a special case. The [help] offers a lot of interesting information, too. Have fun on the site!

Comment: yes, I was guessing you would see the comment anyway because of having commented yourself.
But thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

If your wins are pure luck then the casino cannot prove that you are cheating (because you are not - luck is not cheating).

Though this might be subject to how you define 'prove'. If you are referring to the ability of party A to prove that you are cheating to party B, party B may well accept the beating of astronomical odds as sufficient proof, regardless of whether or not it is a fact. It does not necessarily follow that party A needs to show how you are cheating - party B does not necessarily care.

At this point, the casino could simply refuse to accept any bet from you and escort you from the premises. They would likely notify other casinos.

However, this is your lucky day - your luck is limited to the scope of that day and, within the scope of the day your luck affects not just the fall of the cards, or the spin of the wheel, but also the mood of the casino.

Big wins are not bad news for casinos. Big wins are a chance for good casino publicity. One guy winning big is big news - one guy winning big means that others can win big and that will pull in more punters.

You are lucky. You have not made enough to break the casino, the casino has checks in place to ensure that does not happen, but you have made enough to make yourself and the casino big news. The casino turns you into a superstar - their superstar gambler; they pay your hotel bills, they pay for news coverage - they get you on the radio, they get you on television. They make sure you mention the casino - you will certainly have the t-shirt.

The casino can win big from you winning big.

http://www.new-casinos.uk/bgo-casino-celebrates-2017-with-the-new-mega-fortune-jackpot-winner/

It's just good business.

Answer (score 2):

As per https://www.leg.state.nv.us/NRS/NRS-465.html#NRS465Sec015

> 1.  “Cheat” means to alter the elements of chance, method of selection or criteria which determine:
>         (a) The result of a game;
>         (b) The amount or frequency of payment in a game;
>         (c) The value of a wagering instrument; or
>         (d) The value of a wagering credit.
>         2.  The words and terms defined in chapter 463 of NRS have the meanings
>   ascribed to them in that chapter.
>         (Added to NRS by 1981, 1292; A 1993, 830; 1995, 1502)

---

---

Your premise requires that an operative mechanism with adequate intelligence be monitoring you and contriving circumstances so as to facilitate the conditions of the “luck”.

- Anything I do
- throughout this day
- will yield a successful outcome, no matter what the odds against it are,
  **note:  i use the colloquial denotation of the word “successful” which is synonymous with ‘desired’ or ‘wanted’**
- but only if it's possible to happen in a day.
  **i.e. the event identified as the ‘outcome’ will occur in that day.**

Ergo:  An intelligence adequate for this task would be one which could register your wishes and devise the necessary manipulations which cause that outcome to occur as a result of the actions which you take for the purpose of the outcome.  Furthermore, it seems that your scenario limits the operation of your “luck” to those events which involve probabilities in the scope of so–called [Chaos Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory):  more on that stipulation will be explored later in my answer.
So, nothing like saying “I wish it would rain now!” and expecting it to rain; however, you could say “I want to make it rain today.” and then proceed to throw stones up in to the air in hopes of inciting the clouds to precipitate.

The best way to test this is to present an testable hypothesis — i.e. to try to break the system.

---

Your proposal looks something like this:
You enter the casino.  Your purpose:  to win money through the use of their slot machines.  Each such singular event is composed of two parts:

- the action itself:  operating the lever
- the desired outcome:   that the slot machine will award you the jackpot with each pull

However, there is that lingering question:
Is the act of entering the casino accounted as something performed by you?  If so, then certainly the expected outcome of — wait, what is the expected outcome?  That you be able to operate the slot machines a.k.a. fruit machines unceasingly for the duration of that day?

---

That experiment, however, does not test one critical aspect of the contracted rules:  that the outcome be related to an action performed by you.

Entering the casino is certainly a prerequisite to operating the slots.  However, it doesn't test the limits of the contract.  You could say
“I want to discover a fortune of money as a result of my next footstep.”
However, that also doesn't test the limits:  how much contrivance is your luck able to grant you so as to ensure that an action produce the outcome you desire?

Take this as an experiment:  You want to

- bankrupt a casino,
  *vis–à–vis* win the ownership of all their proprietary assets in their vaults,
- by engaging in each of their games in a manner which does not violate any of their strictures,
- while receiving no resistance from the owners and staff of the casino — elsewise, you would be unable to proceed.

That third one is, obviously, the key.  It is possible for your “luck” to contrive conditions that meet those criteria?

### What exactly does your “luck” change?

I.e., if you lacked the “luck”, what would be different?  What does the “luck” contribute to the environment — what is its participation therein?
You don't say, but we need to remember one thing:  the casino detects cheating by observing certain conditions that alter the probabilities as previously calculated.  They work with probabilities; they work on a level that is unable to predict deterministic reactions, and well above the quantum scale anyways.

### Does your “luck” begin contriving conditions prior to the initial performance of an action?

I.e., can it foresee your wishes?
From your stipulation that it cannot contrive outcomes which would be “impossible”, I conclude:

### No:  it cannot.

Ergo, regardless of how it operates, the “luck” is only capable of orchestrating changes to the environment which it decides are necessary as a result of observing your wishes and the action which you perform whereby to obtain the desired outcome.

Recognizing the mechanism of action employed by the “luck” is quite necessary to determine whether it can affect the attitudes or thoughts of cognitive minds.

Let us consider this rule in the contract:

> no matter what the odds against it are

That seems to imply — rather, declare — that it operates on interactions which occur below the level of determinacy.
Even if we were to grant it unlimited latitude in those mechanisms, it could never actually change the **probability** of an outcome — eh?  Otherwise, if it did, then it wouldn't be something improbable, but something quite probable.

Causing the casino staff to suddenly feel wonderfully fond of you, or to turn a blind eye on your winnings as you won possession of every single chip in the place — that's well within the realm of determinacy.
The first is very unlikely, but could be contrived by improbable events — however, the “luck” can only present you with opportunities to earn that fondness, not grant it to you.
The second would be quite improbable, but would be the best avenue for the “luck” to contrive.

Well, okay.  So, what do we have?  The “luck”

- has no precognition.
- cannot change the environment enough to make the improbable actually probable.
  (Technically, therefore, it is not **cheating**, per se.)
- can only offer opportunities which you must recognize and seize; it cannot give you which is not a product of your actions.

In conclusion:

**So long as you didn't cheat, and only performed actions which could produce outcomes possible through their indeterminacy, then you could complete the experiment and fail to break the envelope.

Oh, and no:  as by my reasoning, the “luck” *does not cheat* for you, then the casino would never see your “luck” as cheating.**

---

Most casinos which have managed to maintain their operation have done so because they control the probability of a bankruptcy.  I could continue with computing that myself, but I don't think it is necessary.  Popular demand could possibly compel me — but maybe not soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the original question, "no" - a casino can *not* prove, or in any way act upon, your luck. Implicit in the premise is that if it is possible to happen, it is obliged to - so long as it deems successful. 
Given that that you want to succeed in obtaining windfall gambling profits, nothing can inhibit that - including the casino actively taking a role against your success. You will be, in fact, cheating (by definition), but it doesn't matter - the setup provided disallows the casino from doing anything to inhibit your success - at least for that day.

**"Anything I do throughout this day will yield a successful outcome, no matter what the odds against it are, but only if it's possible to happen in a day."**

I think it's important to consider your luck in a larger context. Your luck isn't bound to the casino, it applies to every single thing you do that day.

In ways you wouldn't even consciously "wish" - things would simply work in your favor, from security not being able to adequately monitor you, to thieves deciding not to mug you, to the In-N-Out behind the Monte Carlo not giving you dysentery.

Perhaps upon entering the casino, you are told that you are the millionth guest, and have won the entire casino or its contents - your choice.
Maybe you simply win every bet you make, and against all reason, are invited to every other casino on the strip to win there as well.

**Why even stop off in Vegas?**

You only have to set a goal that is possible, however improbable. 
Finding winning Powerball tickets in the gutter, or 100 of them isn't impossible, only improbable.

Of course thinking of it in this context really blows the doors open, and drifts further away from your original question, so I'll refrain from further exploration. 
Needless to say, there are infinite outcomes that aren't impossible that would probably yield better results than the finite funds in a casino (a real estate tycoon uncle you didn't know you had leaves you his empire, etc.)

Comment: Perhaps invent the improbability drive? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCf53ses22w

Comment: @Vylix - I felt that I was clarifying the flawed premise of the question itself (which is a valid answer), but am happy to expound a bit upon that in the answer.

Comment: Not a flawed premise, per se, but it could be executed poorly or illogically or the like.

Comment: Fair point, @can-ned_food. Perhaps stating the premise is  "potentially narrow" is better phrasing than "flawed premise" ?

Comment: @slothluvchunk Nevertheless, I attempted to break it.  Your answer is far better than mine, but I think I explored the premise enough to reach a conclusive answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have not much to add to another answers (about casinos being able to kick you out without any proof of cheating or impossibility of 100% proving you a cheater when you don't cheat), however:

> Of course, if it's impossible, it won't happen.

There is no such thing as "impossible" in our world, there is only "the chance of happening is extremely small" thing. So you need to make up some more solid boundaries for your "ultimate luck" ability.

The "Death Note" mentioned by you and "The Monkey's Paw" are actually telling the stories about what I'm trying to say to you right now:

- It is possible to be [struck by lightning more than 6 times in a lifetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Sullivan)
- It is possible to [survive a 10 kilometers fall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vesna_Vulovi%C4%87)
- It is even possible to [drown in as less as 30mm of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drowning#Cause)
- It is possible to win a roulette 1000 times in a row
- It is possible to suddenly "teleport" from Africa to Las Vegas
- It is possible to be eaten by Tyrannosaurus in your bed while watching Netflix

All of these things are extremely unlikely to happen, yet possible.

Actually when you bring in such a thing like "divine luck" anything is possible, since this "divine luck" can justify any concatenation of circumstances that will lead to the happening of "wished thing" whilst not breaking any fundamental laws of our world.

Comment: Agree on solid boundaries for even magical powers - one cannot expect purely logical answers if mystical forces are at play.

Answer (score 0):

If it was your

> really lucky day

Then the casino wouldn't notice you, you would win *every* game you played, and you would win the most you possibly could win, and at the end of the day, you would probably put the casino into debt & be a <strike>billionaire</strike> trillionaire.

Comment: Becoming a trillionaire in this case is impossible since no matter what, the most you can win is the value of the casino, at which point you become its owner.

Answer (score 0):

"Anything I do throughout this day will yield a successful outcome, no matter what the odds against it are, but only if it's possible to happen in a day."

It is highly unlikely that they're going to take kindly your extreme stroke of luck, or for you to beat the odds of them catching you, or for them to let you keep playing when you're clearly just going to take their money. However, it doesn't matter how unlikely it is, so good luck  in Vegas!

It's also unlikely that they're going to find your winnings to be in their favor, or to be able to spin it into a net win for them, and therefore you. Again, that doesn't matter.

Edit: It's also unlikely that everyone will suffer mass amnesia about the incident, your friends and family will forget about your winnings, and the casino managers will write it off as a loss and forget all about you. But fame is a very fickle thing, and it could be that by tomorrow, the only thing everyone remembers is their shameful frenzy the day before. It is unlikely that everyone will choose to forget, but that's the luck of the draw!

Comment: I definitely need that good luck. Seems my luck has ran out yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could make that one day a game of chance. Flip a coin, throw a dart on a map, base all your actions on pure luck. That way you will keep away from harms way and will probably not get caught.

Casino could "prove" that you are cheating if you keep hitting the same game again and again, but if you win one jackpot on each of the casinos, what can they do?

```
You just need a goal, and the odds will be in your favor.
```

If the above clarification holds true, you could mentally WISH to lose some of the time, just before you move on to the next casino. "Sorry guys, it seems my luck has run out, I better stop while I am winning."

When everything else fails, and you end up in the back room suspected of cheating, they might just throw you out. If the casino does not care too much about the law, after they figure out there are higher forces in play (magic, blessing, luck) they could offer to recruit you - willingly or unwillingly. Tomorrow, when your luck runs out, well, you're really out of luck.

Comment: @Vylix The title of the question is "Can a casino prove..." and it has been noted that an infinitely lucky guy would not get into such situation at the first place, and/or the casino can throw anyone out if they want. Maybe the title of the question should be edited to match the real question. I also noted that someone already presented the idea of "wish to lose this one", so yes, my answer provides only the idea of "let my luck guide me to money safely". Maybe I'll edit my answer as well.

Comment: This guy is not infinitely lucky. There's certain rules to make this works. If you have any additional info that may be worth to the answer, go ahead. Just don't skip what the original answer asked. You can say similar things if you wish.

Comment: @Vylix what he's saying is that the luck applies to any action taken. Therefore, nothing bad can happen as that would be unlucky. For instance, he won't accidentally get hit by a car. He also won't be in a plane crash or be beaten by the mafia. In other words, he is literally untouchable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this luck gets triggered by your intention - until the end of the day, if you intend a lucky but plausible outcome, it happens. So, if you intend to win the maximum jackpot every round of every game you play, yes, that's very suspicious, and you'll be blacklisted after a handful of conspicuous wins. You could get a $30M single jackpot payout (at the boundary of plausible luck), but low six figures would be more likely if you play that way.

However, there's nothing stopping you from looking at the whole Vegas trip as a single venture where your goal is to take as much money as you can from their games without being banned for life. If you play that way, you could probably make hundreds of millions by focusing on gambits to keep them from kicking out out right away - things like losing several hundred grand or a new Ferrari in a side bet with the casino owner might be enough to keep them scratching their heads while you clean up.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with this is that it relies on a misunderstanding of "luck". The universe isn't meaningfully split into unlikely and impossible, at least not the way you think. There is some chance that atoms somewhere will spontaneously rearrange into a cosmic super-being dedicated to granting the lucky persons every wish. It's a very low chance, but some chance.
So sure, there is some chance the casino don't notice. There is some chance all the people looking for cheats at that casino spontaneously transfigure into flamingos. (And a much higher chance they get stuck in traffic, sudden medical emergencies, etc.)

But suppose you have a limited "luck budget". Exactly how is this luck operating? Would this luck cause an early stage cancer that you didn't know was there to die off? Nudge scientists half way around the world in the right direction to invent anti aging drugs. Or is that not happening because our protagonist is too dumb to consider it. Or is that happening as well as the betting.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for getting my grammatical errors. I'm a bit OCD, as when coding, I cannot stand errors or seeing lines with only one character or word. And, I'm pretty sure that it's not cheating if they don't know about luck manipulation being a thing (unless the casino has a penchant for being ridiculously overprepared), and thus won't have any rules against it. In that case, it's not technically cheating, so it's okay, even though it gives you an unfair advantage. Or, if it allows, even encourages cheating, nobody would care enough anyways to outlaw luck manipulation.